# Getting all pages information from XML response

Tags: xml, api

When I am sending a XML request to API with having required parameters for Pagination Information, I am sending page number as 1 (Default value is 1) and page size as 10. How can I request for all pages information and get response for all pages , but just not for page 1?

This is the request I am sending

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><PrivateOptionsAPIRequest> 
     Other part of my XML Request
  <PaginationInformation><PageNumber>1</PageNumber><PageSize>10</PageSize></PaginationInformation></PrivateOptionsAPIRequest>
```

Comment: It probably depends on the API you are using. There is no general pagination mechanism that works for every api and the app in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't.

The whole point of pagination is that you don't request ALL the data, as it may be just too much. Are you ready to receive and process 5GB file?

If the certain API doesn't allow you to request all the data, you need to send multiple requests, one for each page.

Make sure that you refer to the documentation and/or contact the owner of the system you're connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put some big number into PageSize element. Something like:
`<PageNumber>1</PageNumber><PageSize>1000000</PageSize>`.

Answer (score 0):

0) There is no uniform answer.

1) Some APIs return a NEXT item or similar, which can be used to get the next page of results, often in the form of a URL that can be GETted or parameters that can be POSTed.

2) The correct way to get a paginated API is to make requests with:

`<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>`

`<PageNumber>2</PageNumber>`

etc., iterating over the number of pages, which may be in the API somewhere. If it isn't, stop when it's no longer returning you `PageSize` elements or the container for the elements has disappeared. (The number of elements may fail interestingly on some APIs if the number of items is divisible by `PageSize`and requesting pages past the end returns the first (which some do.))

3) Boosting the page size isn't likely to work: most APIs set it to the maximum permitted; some badly-written APIs break if you give them too big numbers.